# Django Rest API complain about swagger version

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, swagger

We are using DJango rest framework to make api. We added swagger page, but its complain about swagger version.

```
Unable to render this definition

The provided definition does not specify a valid version field.

Please indicate a valid Swagger or OpenAPI version field. Supported version fields are swagger: "2.0" and those that match openapi: 3.0.n (for example, openapi: 3.0.0).
```

I was following documentation https://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/documenting-your-api/#a-minimal-example-with-swagger-ui

Below are files.

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    ...
    path("openapi", get_schema_view(
            title="My api",
            description="API for me",
            version="1.0.0"
        ), name="openapi-schema"),
    path('swagger-ui/', TemplateView.as_view(
        template_name='swagger-ui.html',
        extra_context={'schema_url':'openapi-schema'}
    ), name='swagger-ui')
]
```

**templates/swagger-ui.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Swagger</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//unpkg.com/swagger-ui-dist@3/swagger-ui.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="swagger-ui"></div>
    <script src="//unpkg.com/swagger-ui-dist@3/swagger-ui-bundle.js"></script>
    <script>
    const ui = SwaggerUIBundle({
        url: "{% url schema_url %}",
        dom_id: '#swagger-ui',
        presets: [
          SwaggerUIBundle.presets.apis,
          SwaggerUIBundle.SwaggerUIStandalonePreset
        ],
        layout: "BaseLayout",
        requestInterceptor: (request) => {
          request.headers['X-CSRFToken'] = "{{ csrf_token }}"
          return request;
        }
      })
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I think, its complaining about `version: 1.0.0` mentioned in `openapi` schema view. But need to sure, if something else is not causing this issue.

Comment: Your OpenAPI YAML/JSON definition file that lives at `schema_url` must include either the `"openapi": "3.0.0"` or `"swagger": "2.0"` field at the root level.

Comment: @Helen `schema_url` map to `openapi` url, and that `openapi` has `get_schema_view` function with `version="1.0.0"` are you talking about to change that version ?

Comment: No, `version="1.0.0"` becomes the `info.version` key. But frameworks usually automatically add or provide a way to manually specify the `"openapi": "3.0.0"` or `"swagger": "2.0"` key.

Comment: @Helen I am refering documentation for `get_schema_view` but it has no option to pass `openapi` or `swagger` version. https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/schemas/#get_schema_view is the link which I am following.